# Resampling multivariate time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a set of bivariate time series and want to resample them to the same length. I thought that it might be a good idea to use the mean length of all time series, since I wanted to avoid that some series  will be shortened or extended too much. My first naive idea was using the resample method of the signal package, and resample each dimension of a series separately. I don't like this idea very much, since I have the fear that the alignment between the dimensions might suffer from the independent resampling, but I hoped this effect might be negligible.

My current problem is that the resampling of the data creates artifacts at the end and beginning of a series. It seems that the resample method assumes that the series starts from zero. Now I'm wondering if there is a more suitable resampling method which in the best case is readily available (in R) and maybe also supports bivariate time series.

Plot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OwAt.png

Code example:

```
example <- c(-2014.1, -2014.1, -2014.1, -2014, -2014, -2013.9, -2013.9, 
-2013.7, -2013.5, -2013.4, -2013.1, -2012.9, -2012.6, -2012.4, 
-2012, -2011.7, -2011.4, -2011, -2010.5, -2010.1, -2009.5, -2009.1, 
-2008.6, -2008, -2007.5, -2006.9, -2006.4, -2005.7, -2005.1, 
-2004.4, -2003.7, -2003, -2002.4, -2001.5, -2000.7, -1999.9, 
-1999.1, -1998.2, -1997.4, -1996.5, -1995.6, -1994.6, -1993.6, 
-1992.6, -1991.7, -1990.7, -1989.7, -1988.9, -1987.9, -1986.9, 
-1985.9, -1984.9, -1984, -1983, -1982.1, -1981.1, -1980.1, -1979.2, 
-1978.2, -1977.2, -1976.4, -1975.4, -1974.4, -1973.4, -1972.4, 
-1971.5, -1970.5, -1969.6, -1968.6, -1967.6, -1966.6, -1965.7, 
-1964.7, -1963.9, -1962.9, -1961.9, -1960.9, -1959.9, -1958.9, 
-1957.9, -1956.9, -1955.9, -1955, -1954, -1953, -1952.1, -1951.5, 
-1951.1, -1950.6, -1950.1, -1949.6, -1949.2, -1948.7, -1948.2, 
-1947.9, -1947.4, -1946.9, -1946.4, -1945.9, -1945.4, -1944.9, 
-1944.4, -1943.9, -1943.4, -1943, -1942.5, -1942, -1941.5, -1941, 
-1940.6, -1940.1, -1939.6, -1939.1, -1938.7, -1938.2, -1937.7, 
-1937.2, -1936.7, -1936.2, -1935.7, -1935.4, -1934.9, -1934.4, 
-1933.9, -1933.4, -1932.9, -1932.4, -1931.9, -1931.4, -1931, 
-1930.5, -1930, -1929.5, -1929, -1928.6, -1928.1, -1927.6, -1927.1, 
-1926.6, -1926.2, -1925.7, -1925.2, -1924.7, -1924.4, -1923.9, 
-1923.4, -1922.9, -1922.4, -1921.9, -1921.4, -1920.9, -1920.4, 
-1919.9, -1919.4, -1919, -1918.5, -1918, -1917.5, -1917, -1916.6, 
-1916.1, -1915.6, -1915.1, -1914.6, -1914.2, -1913.7, -1913.2, 
-1912.7, -1912.2, -1911.7, -1911.4, -1910.9, -1910.4, -1909.9, 
-1909.4, -1908.9, -1908.4, -1907.9, -1907.5, -1906.9, -1906.5, 
-1906, -1905.5, -1905, -1904.6, -1904, -1903.6, -1903.1, -1902.7, 
-1902.2, -1901.7, -1901.2, -1900.7, -1900.4, -1899.9, -1899.4, 
-1898.9, -1898.4, -1897.9, -1897.4, -1896.9, -1896.4, -1895.9, 
-1895.2, -1895, -1894.5, -1894, -1893.6, -1893.1, -1892.6, -1892.1, 
-1891.6, -1891.2, -1890.7, -1890.2, -1889.7, -1889.2, -1888.9, 
-1888.4, -1887.9, -1887.4, -1886.9, -1886.4, -1885.6, -1885.4, 
-1884.9, -1884.5, -1884, -1883.5, -1883, -1882.5, -1882.1, -1881.6, 
-1881.1, -1880.6, -1880.2, -1879.7, -1879.2, -1878.7, -1878.4, 
-1877.9, -1877.4, -1876.9, -1876.1, -1875.6, -1875.1, -1874.6, 
-1874.1, -1873.6, -1873.2, -1872.7, -1872.2, -1871.7, -1871.4, 
-1870.7, -1870.4, -1869.9, -1869.4, -1868.9, -1868.4, -1867.9, 
-1867.4, -1867.2, -1866.4, -1866, -1865.5, -1865, -1864.5, -1864.1, 
-1863.6, -1863.1, -1862.6, -1862.1, -1861.7, -1861.2, -1860.7, 
-1860.2, -1859.7, -1859.4, -1858.9, -1858.4, -1857.9, -1857.4, 
-1856.9, -1856.4, -1855.9, -1855.4, -1854.9, -1854.5, -1854, 
-1853.5, -1853.1, -1852.6, -1852.1, -1851.6, -1851.1, -1850.7, 
-1850.2, -1849.7, -1849.2)

plot(example, t="l", main="Original")
plot(resample(example,250,length(example)), t="l", main="Resampled")
```

Comment: what do you mean by resample? what kind of algorithm do you want to apply?

Comment: Basically I want to resize all time series to the same length (think of interpolation or decimation). Ideally the information loss should be minimal. In the example above I've used the resample function of the ["signal" R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/signal/signal.pdf).

Comment: and for what further treatment? As example,if you want to find correlation between time series, you do not need to have the same length (use DTW , even if it does not catch the dynamic).

Comment: Actually one purpose is to reduce the time series size to speed up the DTW calculations (a few millions). Another is to evaluate an indexing approach which requires equal length time series.